# Highlight cells in A:A that contain "X" when cells in B:B are identical

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In this example, column A contains email addresses and column B contains unique identifiers for each student.  Sometimes a student has two "different" email addresses (e.g. johndoe@school.edu and jdoe@school.edu) that go to the same inbox.  Sometimes that student also has a personal email (e.g. johndoe@gmail.com).  Their unique identifier in column B might be jdoe1.  In this person's case, I'd like to send a total of two emails - one to **one of the two** school email addresses and another to the personal email address.

My thought was that I'd have to do this somewhat manually.  But basically, I'd like Excel 2016 to highlight the cells that contain "@school.edu" if a single unique identifier has two or more corresponding cells in column A which contain "@school.edu"

An example of how my sheet looks can be seen here:

```
Email               Identifier
jdoe@school.edu     jdoe1
jdoe1@school.edu    jdoe1
johndoe@school.edu  jdoe1
marywilliams@gmail.com  mwill2
mwill@school.edu    mwill2
marywill@school.edu mwill2
mwilly12@yahoo.com  mwill2
cteabert@school.edu christ1
cteab1@school.edu   christ1
```

There are three unique students, and each student has multiple emails from @school.edu.  In the end, I would like each student to only have one row which contains @school.edu.

If anything is unclear, I can explain in more detail.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why not use a formula to pull out the email address to use rather than just highlight it. Then if you do a bit more reading about VBA you could send the emails automatically too. If you could show us some of your example data we can help a bit more

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean about pulling out the ones to use...  How would I go about that?  And I can't share the data since it's protected - but I could make up an example sheet if that helps.

Comment: If you could edit your question to include an example of what's in column A and B that would be great.

Comment: @CallumDA - Added the example and a quick explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer returns the following. It finds the first school email and personal email (if any).

[image]

As you can see you need to add a few more columns to your data. In cell `C2` place the following formula and drag down:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("@school.edu",A2)),"Personal","School")
```

In `D3` place the following formula and drag down:

```
=B2&C2
```

Now you need a list of identifiers (no duplicates). You can do this by copying and pasting your list of names to a different location (perhaps a different sheet) then highlight the whole column and press Data>Remove Duplicates

I placed this list in `G2:G4`. You can then put the following formula into `H2` and drag down and across. Note that you need the headings `School` and `Personal`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH($G2&H$1,$D$2:$D$10,0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed response.  I can follow exactly what you are doing and made it work for my data.